# Inserting a table name into a query gives sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I want to dynamically choose what table to use in a SQL query, but I just keep getting error however I am trying to format this. Also tried `%s` instead of `?`.

Any suggestions?

```
group_food = (group, food)
group_food_new = (group, food, 1)

with con:

    cur = con.cursor() 
    tmp = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM (?) WHERE Name=?", group_food)

    if tmp == 0:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO ? VALUES(?, ?)", group_food_new)
    else: 
        times_before = cur.execute("SELECT Times FROM ? WHERE Name=?", group_food)
        group_food_update = (group, (times_before +1), food)

        cur.execute("UPDATE ? SET Times=? WHERE Name=?", group_food_update)
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You cannot use SQL parameters to be placeholders in SQL objects; one of the *reasons* for using a SQL parameters is to escape the value such that the database can never mistake the contents for a database object.

You'll have to interpolate the database objects separately; escape your identifiers by doubling any `"` double quote parameters and use

```
cur.execute('SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM "{}" WHERE Name=?'.format(group.replace('"', '""')), (food,))
```

and

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO "{}" VALUES(?, ?)'.format(group.replace('"', '""')), (food, 1))
```

and

```
cur.execute('UPDATE "{}" SET Times=? WHERE Name=?'.format(group.replace('"', '""')),
            (times_before + 1, food))
```

The `".."` double quotes are there to properly demark an identifier, even if that identifier is also a valid keyword; any existing `"` characters in the name must be doubled; this also helps de-fuse SQL injection attempts.

However, if your object names are user-sourced, you'll have to do your own (stringent) validation on the object names to prevent SQL injection attacks here. Always validate them against existing objects in that case.

You should really consider using a project like [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) to generate your SQL instead; it can take care of validating object names and rigorously protect you from SQL injection risks. It can [load your table definitions up front](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html#reflecting-all-tables-at-once) so it'll know what names are legal:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, select, MetaData

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////path/to/database')
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
conn = engine.connect()

group_table = meta.tables[group]  # can only find existing tables
count_statement = select([func.count(group_table.c.Name)], group_table.c.Name == food)
count, = conn.execute(count_statement).fetchone()
if count:
    # etc.
```

Comment: ah! So '?' place holders are only for SQL *values* - and cannot be used for SQL table names etc.?

Comment: @colminator: exactly. Otherwise there'd be a massive security hole, where someone would add in `'; DROP TABLE VALUES --`, or other such shenanigans. That's one of the major reasons to use SQL parameters (always use SQL parameters, it's the secure thing to do!).

Comment: Understood from a *values* perspective, but I'm referring to tables and column names.   I've always wanted to extend SQL parameterization convenience to table names and columns in a generic way. Case in point, when comparing two databases with differing schemas (i.e. columns do not match) I want make the import and export columns programmatically determined. While there *shouldn't* be any special characters in the column names, it would be nice to safely escape them to remove any potential for SQL errors.

Comment: @colminator: Nope, object names are indeed not possible with parameters. Use a SQL generator like SQLAlchemy or the [PsycoPG `sql` module](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) for tasks like that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why are object names not possible with parameters? Would that be less safe than using the `format` method and not performing any sanitization on the table/column names?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: because the usecase for parameters is to escape data, and there is no easy path to detecting that something is an object name instead. You can't be sure from context if something is used as data or an object name, for example. `WHERE colname = ?` can take both an object name and data, for example.

Answer (score 1):

What are the values of group and food? The guidelines say to make the question as such others can benefit from it, for that to be the case here we need the values of group and food.

It seems you use the Python String formatter instead of SQL parameters for table names even though https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3 says using the String formatter in unsafe.

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
```

Using `%s` as a placeholder then putting `%` outside the string with the variables in Python2 has been Replaced in Python3 with `.format()` function with the variables as arguments.

Answer (score -4):

I've found building the SQL query up as a text string and then passing this string into the c.execute() function works.

```
querySelect = "SELECT * FROM " + str(your_table_variable)
queryWhere = " WHERE " + str(variableName) + " = " str(variableValue)
query = querySelect + queryWhere
c.execute(query)
```

I don't know the security situation around it though (re injection) and I'm sure there are probably better ways of doing this.

Comment: Don't do this. It is the definition of injection.

Comment: Try adding `your_table_variable = your_table_variable + '; DELETE FROM ' + your_table_variable` before that code. (No, seriously, don't.)