# Syntax error when assigning field name variable to a "?" placeholder

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, syntax-error

I am trying to make a method which will allow me to edit existing data in an SQLite3 database. The relevant part of the code which throws an error is this:

```
    self.chosen = "Example_column"    # Column reference
    self.edited = "Something"         # Replacement value for chosen/chooseAccount reference
    self.chooseAccount = 1            # Primary key, in column called "ID"

    self.sql = "UPDATE Accounts_CV SET ?=? WHERE ID=?;"
    c.execute(sql, (self.chosen, self.edited, self.chooseAccount,))
    c.commit()
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johntamm-buckle/Documents/python scripts/accounts/cv_main.py", line 44, in <module>
    mainLoop()
  File "/Users/johntamm-buckle/Documents/python scripts/accounts/cv_main.py", line 24, in mainLoop
    db.editEntry()
  File "/Users/johntamm-buckle/Documents/python scripts/accounts/db_handler/db_handler.py", line 125, in editEntry
    c.execute(self.sql, (self.chosen, self.edited, self.chooseAccount,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Am I not able to assign the field reference to a `?` placeholder?  If not, what is the recommended way to edit a specific ID/field reference, where both the ID and field reference are dynamic?

Comment: If the field name isn't user input, it's OK to `str.format` it into your query, leaving the `?`s for the values. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6514274/3001761

Comment: Thank you, that solved it!  Yes, the field name comes from a dict and isn't user specified.  I still don't understand why the '?' placeholder didn't work though.  My apologies for asking a duplicate question - I'm pretty new to this and think I needed a more specific answer  to my question than I could get from questions like this - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387537/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387537/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error?rq=1).

Comment: Because that's for values, not field names