# Python sqlite3 OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

Trying to let users update column values on existing records for a specific table named "Scenario."  The record being updated is identified by an index column called "Scenario_Key", unique to each instance of this class.  The code I already have produces a dictionary of key, value pairs where `key` is the name of the column being updated and `value` is the value being inserted into it.  To update the sqlite database I'm trying the following:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE Scenario SET ?=? WHERE Scenario_Key=?;""", (key, new_val, self.scenario_key))
```

But when I try to execute by clicking the "Save and Close" button, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/Users/xxx/Documents/Consulting/DCA/Damage Control Assistant/EditScenarioWindow.py", line 91, in <lambda>
SaveAndCloseButton = Button(ButtonFrame, text="Save and Close", command=lambda: self.SaveAndCloseWindow())
File "/Users/xxx/Documents/Consulting/DCA/Damage Control Assistant/EditScenarioWindow.py", line 119, in SaveAndCloseWindow
cursor.execute(cmd_string, (key, new_val, self.scenario_key))
OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

I've read over [sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387537/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error), but I'm trying to do a single sqlite query where all the variables have already been calculated, not get values from the database and build a query from there.  I'm supplying the positional arguments as a tuple.  So why doesn't sqlite3 like the query I'm submitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parametrize column names. While being cognisant of the possibility of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, you could instead do:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE Scenario 
                     SET {}=? 
                   WHERE Scenario_Key=?;""".format(key), 
               (new_val, self.scenario_key))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  This worked, and even better, I think I understand why.

Thanks also for the warning.  For a variety of reasons security and injection attacks aren't a major concern for this project, but definitely something to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you!