# SQL Update Syntax "," Error

Tags: python, sql, sql-update

I have an update query which is returning an error, this is the code:

```
self.cur.execute("UPDATE Trainers SET Name=?, DOB=?, Gender=?",(Name, DOB, Gender))
```

This is the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

Comment: Have a look, maybe it will help you: [sqlite3.OperationalError: near “?”: syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387537/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error) OR [Python sqlite3 OperationalError: near “?”: syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577182/python-sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error)

Comment: HI, I edited the code as in these questions and it is still returning the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use curly braces it will help you.

```
self.cur.execute("UPDATE Trainers SET Name={}, DOB={}, Gender={}",(Name, DOB, Gender))
```

Comment: Hi, that returns the error `IndexError: tuple index out of rang`

Comment: If are getting this issue. It should not throw any error. you can use alternative syntax as well.

self.cur.execute("UPDATE Trainers SET Name=%s, DOB=%s, Gender=%s",(Name, DOB, Gender))

These might be the alternative solution