# How do I insert variables in the UPDATE Statement sqlite3 with Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

If I want to insert a variable value in sqlite3 with python you code the following statement. For example:

```
import sqlite3
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect('testing.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing(Name TEXT, Telephone TEXT, ID REAL)")

var1 = input("Value:")
var2 = input("Value:")
var3 = random.randint(1,20)

c.execute("INSERT INTO testing VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (var1, var2, var3))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

What if I want to do the same with the **UPDATE** statement. I tried this and is giving me error:

```
column = input("Column to update:")
update_user = input("Value to update:")
field_name = input("Where field name equal to:")
value = input("Value")

c.execute("UPDATE testing SET ? = ? WHERE ? = ?", (column, update_user, field_name, value))

conn.commit()
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Comment: copy the error and post it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387537/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a common problem, in your update query, you *cannot parameterize the column names*. In other words:

```
UPDATE testing SET ? = ? WHERE ? = ?
               THIS^       THIS^
```

cannot be query placeholders and you have to insert them the usual way - via string formatting:

```
c.execute("""
    UPDATE 
        testing 
    SET 
        {0} = ? 
    WHERE 
        {1} = ?""".format(column, field_name), (update_user, value))
```

Though, you should be careful about properly sanitizing, validating the `column` and `field_name` values to prevent [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Even though this was asked and answered before in different variations, I'll leave this answer since it points out what happens and what to do in this particular use case.