# python sqlite3 unrecognized token: "{"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

This syntax:

```
consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE rut LIKE '%"+str(cadena)+"%'".format(tablepx))
```

produces an error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: "{"
```

I tried with this too:

```
consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE rut LIKE ?".format(tablepx),(cadena,))
```

It doesn't send error but nothing happens, it doesn't work as I get zero results from the database.

I don't know how to work with `'%" + str(cadena) +"%'`, I always work with `.format()`.

Comment: What does `str(cadena)` look like?

Comment: ah, the daily question about concatenating SQL queries. **Don't**. Use a parametrized query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting the last section of your string:

```
"%'".format(tablepx)
```

before concatenating that to the result of `"..." + str(cadena)`. So the `{0}` placeholder in the *first* string literal is not filled and you are left with `"SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE rut LIKE '%...%'"` as the query (with `...` replaced by the value of `cadena`).

You could fix that by moving the `.format()` call to the `"SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE rut LIKE '%"` string literal instead. Or by using a second placeholder `{1}` to show where the `cadeda` value should go, instead of using `+` concatenations.

**However**, you should not be using string concatenation to put `cadena` into the string in the first place. You had the right idea, by using the `?` placeholder and a query parameter value, but you forgot to add the `%` LIKE query characters to your `cadena` value.

Simply add `%` characters to the start and end of `cadena`, then use the result of that as your parameter:

```
like_string = '%{0}%'.format(cadena)
consulta.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE rut LIKE ?".format(tablepx),
    (like_string,))
```

The `?` placeholder in the query string will be used to place a properly escaped `LIKE` query string, with `%` added to the start and end of the `cadena` value.

I can't stress enough that using `str.format()` to interpolate a table name into a query string (as you do with `tablepx`) can open you up to SQL injection issues. See [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387537/inserting-a-table-name-into-a-query-gives-sqlite3-operationalerror-near-sy/25387570#25387570) for more advice on this, as well as alternatives. To be safe, I'd at least use `"{0}"` as the table name position and `tablepx.replace('"', '""')`, so that SQLite at least knows to only accept valid object names in that part of the string:

```
like_string = '%{0}%'.format(cadena)
consulta.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM "{0}" WHERE rut LIKE ?'.format(tablepx.replace('"', '""')),
    (like_string,))
```

Comment: thank men i trayed this consulta.execute("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE rut LIKE '%{1}%'".format(tablepx,cadena))  and work good, thank u

Comment: @Giova: however, I'd *really not use that format*, because any untrusted party that can set the `cadena` value can hack your database.

Comment: what can i do to avoid hack?

Comment: @Giova: by using the syntax at the end of my answer. If `tablepx` is not something that a user supplies (or can supply part of the value for) then the first example in my answer would suffice. Both create `like_string` by adding `%` to the start and end of `cadena` first, then use `like_string` as a parameter for the query.