# Variable values for sqlite3 table Python string formatter arguments

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to run this snippet I found, but the variables for `group` and `food` are not defined.

```
group_food = (group, food)
group_food_new = (group, food, 1)

with con:

    cur = con.cursor() 
    tmp = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(Name) FROM (?) WHERE Name=?", group_food)
    
    if tmp == 0:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO ? VALUES(?, ?)", group_food_new)
    else: 
        times_before = cur.execute("SELECT Times FROM ? WHERE Name=?", group_food)
        group_food_update = (group, (times_before +1), food)

        cur.execute("UPDATE ? SET Times=? WHERE Name=?", group_food_update)
```

What would example variables be that would make this code snippet work?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os, sqlite3

print("Store certbot expiries in DB...")

File = os.path.realpath(__file__)
database_path = File.replace(".py", ".db")

connection = sqlite3.connect(database_path)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Check if table exists
# https://pythonexamples.org/python-sqlite3-check-if-table-exists/#2
# c.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='students1' ''')
table_name = "certificates"
t = (table_name,)
cursor.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{}' '''.format(table_name))

domain = "operation420.net"
# https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/
if not cursor.fetchone()[0] == 1 :
    print('Table "{}" does not exist, creating...'.format(table_name))
    #t = (table_name,)
    sql_string = "CREATE TABLE '{}' (domain name, expiry)".format(table_name)
    print(sql_string)
    #cursor.execute(sql_string, t)
    cursor.execute(sql_string)
else:
    pass


#cmd = input("Command?> ")
cmd = 'n'       #################

table_name = "certificates"
new = ['n', "N", 'new', "NEW", "New", "nEW"]
new.extend([ 'create'  ])
if cmd.upper() in new:
    #### 04 Aug 20
    year = input("Year?> ")
    month_str = input("Month?> ")
    month_str = "{}".format(month_str).upper()
    if month_str == '1': month_str = '01'
    if month_str == '2': month_str = '02'
    if month_str == '3': month_str = '03'
    if month_str == '4': month_str = '04'
    if month_str == '5': month_str = '05'
    if month_str == '6': month_str = '06'
    if month_str == '7': month_str = '07'
    if month_str == '8': month_str = '08'
    if month_str == '9': month_str = '09'
    month = None
    Jan = [ "01", "JAN", ]
    Jan.extend([ "JANUARY" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Jan: month = "01"
    Feb = [ "02", "FEB", "FE" ]
    Feb.extend([ "F", "february".upper() ])
    if month_str.upper() in Feb: month = '02'
    Mar = [ '03', 'MAR' ]
    Mar.extend([ 'MARCH', "MR"])
    if month_str.upper() in Mar: month = '03'
    Apr = [ '04', 'APR' ]
    Apr.extend([ "APRIL", "A", 'AP'])
    if month_str.upper() in Apr: month = '04'
    May = [ '05', 'MAY' ]
    May.extend([ "MAY", "MY" ])
    if month_str.upper() in May: month = '05'
    Jun = [ '06', 'JUN' ]
    Jun.extend([ 'JUNE', "JN", "JE" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Jun: month = '06'
    Jul = [ '07', 'JUL' ]
    Jul.extend([ 'JULY', "JL" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Jul: month = '07'
    Aug = [ '08', 'AUG' ]
    Aug.extend([ "AUGUST", 'AG' ])
    if month_str.upper() in Aug: month = '08'
    Sep = [ '09', 'SEP', "SEPT", "S" ]
    Sep.extend([ 'SEPTEMBER', "SE", "SPT" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Sep: month = '09'
    Oct = [ '10', 'OCT', 'OC' ]
    Oct.extend([ 'OCTOBER', "O", "OT" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Oct: month = '10'
    Nov = [ '11', 'NOV', 'NV' ]
    Nov.extend([ 'NOVEMBER', 'NO', "N" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Nov: month = '11'
    Dec = [ '12', 'DEC' ]
    Dec.extend([ 'DECEMBER', "D", "DC" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Dec: month = '12'
    ##
    day = input("Day?> ")
    if day == '1': day = '01'
    if day == '2': day = '02'
    if day == '3': day = '03'
    if day == '4': day = '04'
    if day == '5': day = '05'
    if day == '6': day = '06'
    if day == '7': day = '07'
    if day == '8': day = '08'
    if day == '9': day = '09'
    ##
    expiry = "{}-{}-{}".format(year, month, day)
    print("Domain {} expires on {}".format(domain, expiry))
    command = 'INSERT INTO "{}" VALUES("{}","{}")'.format(table_name,domain,expiry)
    # Don't think command is the right term but Whatever...
    print(command)
    cursor.execute(command)




# End
```

Comment: There are no variables that would make that code work; table names (and column names) cannot be parametrized in sqlite

Comment: Is that true for both snippets (the example one I posted, and the code I am working with)? So you cannot get table names from variables? They have to be hard coded?

Comment: I seen suggestions to use "string1 {}".format("string2") but wouldn't that be insecure? https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3 says not to use `symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)` but that's using Python2's %s formatter not Python3 .format() but don't those ways do the same thing in the end ("under the hood")?

Comment: I am not sure what the lines `group_food = (group, food)    
group_food_new = (group, food, 1)` mean, defining tuples to those variables?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this info from the [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) will save a lot code:

> It is usually an error to attempt to create a new table in a database that already contains a table, index or view of the same name. However, if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified as part of the CREATE TABLE statement and a table or view of the same name already exists, the CREATE TABLE command simply has no effect (and no error message is returned). An error is still returned if the table cannot be created because of an existing index, even if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified.

The snippet is using the "qmark" style described in the [execute documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). But will not work with using the sqlite3 library because table names/column names cannot be parametrized.

Comment: Thank you, the `IF NOT EXISTS` statement would be of great use. I'll review the docs. I don't know much about SQL so out of habit was doing everything I could in Python. This is a great learning experience for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os, sqlite3

print("Store certbot expiries in DB...")

File = os.path.realpath(__file__)
database_path = File.replace(".py", ".db")

connection = sqlite3.connect(database_path)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Check if table exists
# https://pythonexamples.org/python-sqlite3-check-if-table-exists/#2
# c.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='students1' ''')
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387537/inserting-a-table-name-into-a-query-gives-sqlite3-operationalerror-near-sy
table_name = "certificates"
t = (table_name,)
cursor.execute(''' SELECT count(name) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{}' '''.format(table_name))

# https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/
if not cursor.fetchone()[0] == 1 :
    print('Table "{}" does not exist, creating...'.format(table_name))
    #t = (table_name,)
    sql_string = "CREATE TABLE '{}' (domain name, expiry)".format(table_name)
    print(sql_string)
    #cursor.execute(sql_string, t)
    cursor.execute(sql_string)
else:
    pass

#cmd = input("Command?> ")
cmd = 'ls'      #################


lst = ["LS", "SHOW" ]
if cmd.upper() in lst:
    pass

new = ['n', "N", 'new', "NEW", "New", "nEW"]
new.extend([ 'create'  ])
if cmd.upper() in new:
    #### 04 Aug 20
    domain = input("Domain?> ")
    year = input("Year?> ")
    month_str = input("Month?> ")
    month_str = "{}".format(month_str).upper()
    if month_str == '1': month_str = '01'
    if month_str == '2': month_str = '02'
    if month_str == '3': month_str = '03'
    if month_str == '4': month_str = '04'
    if month_str == '5': month_str = '05'
    if month_str == '6': month_str = '06'
    if month_str == '7': month_str = '07'
    if month_str == '8': month_str = '08'
    if month_str == '9': month_str = '09'
    month = None
    Jan = [ "01", "JAN", ]
    Jan.extend([ "JANUARY" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Jan: month = "01"
    Feb = [ "02", "FEB", "FE" ]
    Feb.extend([ "F", "february".upper() ])
    if month_str.upper() in Feb: month = '02'
    Mar = [ '03', 'MAR' ]
    Mar.extend([ 'MARCH', "MR"])
    if month_str.upper() in Mar: month = '03'
    Apr = [ '04', 'APR' ]
    Apr.extend([ "APRIL", "A", 'AP'])
    if month_str.upper() in Apr: month = '04'
    May = [ '05', 'MAY' ]
    May.extend([ "MAY", "M", "MA" ])
    if month_str.upper() in May: month = '05'
    Jun = [ '06', 'JUN' ]
    Jun.extend([ 'JUNE', "JN", "JE" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Jun: month = '06'
    Jul = [ '07', 'JUL' ]
    Jul.extend([ 'JULY', "JL" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Jul: month = '07'
    Aug = [ '08', 'AUG' ]
    Aug.extend([ "AUGUST", 'AG' ])
    if month_str.upper() in Aug: month = '08'
    Sep = [ '09', 'SEP', "SEPT", "S" ]
    Sep.extend([ 'SEPTEMBER', "SE", "SPT" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Sep: month = '09'
    Oct = [ '10', 'OCT', 'OC' ]
    Oct.extend([ 'OCTOBER', "O", "OT" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Oct: month = '10'
    Nov = [ '11', 'NOV', 'NV' ]
    Nov.extend([ 'NOVEMBER', 'NO', "N" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Nov: month = '11'
    Dec = [ '12', 'DEC' ]
    Dec.extend([ 'DECEMBER', "D", "DC" ])
    if month_str.upper() in Dec: month = '12'
    ##
    day = input("Day?> ")
    if day == '1': day = '01'
    if day == '2': day = '02'
    if day == '3': day = '03'
    if day == '4': day = '04'
    if day == '5': day = '05'
    if day == '6': day = '06'
    if day == '7': day = '07'
    if day == '8': day = '08'
    if day == '9': day = '09'
    ##
    expiry = "{}-{}-{}".format(year, month, day)
    print("Domain {} expires on {}".format(domain, expiry))
    command = 'INSERT INTO "{}" VALUES("{}","{}")'.format(table_name,domain,expiry)
    # Don't think command is the right term but Whatever...
    print(command)
    cursor.execute(command)
    connection.commit()




# End
```